Код не продолжает работу
from idlelib.undo import Command
from imaplib import Commands
from turtledemo.penrose import start
from aiogram.filters import Command
from aiogram import Dispatcher, types, Bot, F
import asyncio

dp = Dispatcher()

@dp.message(Command("start"))
async def start(message: types.Message):
    kb = [
        [types.KeyboardButton(text = "Каталог")],
        [
            types.KeyboardButton(text = "Профиль"),
            types.KeyboardButton(text = "Тех.поддержка")
        ],
        [
            types.KeyboardButton(text = "О нас")
        ]
    ]
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard = kb,
resize_keyboard=True)
    await message.answer("Привет,это бот по продаже курсов",
reply_markup=keyboard)

@dp.message(F.text.lower() == "Каталог")
async def katlog(message : types.Message):
    key = [
        [
            types.KeyboardButton(text = "Курс по Python"),
            types.KeyboardButton(text="Курс по Aiogram")
        ],
        [
            types.KeyboardButton(text = "Курс по Telebot"),
            types.KeyboardButton(text = "Курс по Django")
        ]
    ]
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True,
keyboard=key),
    await message.answer("Выбери нужный курс",
reply_markup=keyboard)


async def main():
    bot = Bot(token = "6803465461:AAGvxKRz5biDkSNy6B91yaiyA4Z")
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

После ввода слова "Каталог" не выходят другие 4 кнопки,в консоли ничего не отображается - 0 ошибок

что по вашему должен делать фильтр F.text.lower()? Подсказка: каталог != Каталог

ну и токен не забудьте сменить
